# how to display intime and outtime in different columns

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

[the intime and outtime are in columns , but i need them like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anond.jpg)[I want it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuWzs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need to use the [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) operator. Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) similar to yours that has been answered.

Noel